# Load PDF from API without caching

Tags: angularjs, web

I generate a report by calling an API that return a PDF to the client. Problem is after one load the call is cached and the API isn't called anymore so the report won't be updated if it need to be.

I use this piece of code to get my report in a new window:

```
$window.open("generate/my/pdf");
```

Is there another way that will call the API every time (and won't trigger some anti pop-up)?

Comment: `$window.open("generate/my/pdf?" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));`

Answer (score 0):

add a differnt number to the end of the url, using the `?` character at the end of your string will treat the numbers as a parameter, changing the url and not caching it.

`$window.open("generate/my/pdf?" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));`